# Avoiding thumbnail name collisions with sorl-thumbnail

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

Understanding that I should probably just dig into the source to come up with a solution, I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a tactic for dealing with this.

In my project, I have *a lot* of images being generated outside of the application.  I'm isolating them on the filesystem based on a model's pk.

For example, a model instance with a pk of 121 might have the following images:

```
.../src_pics/1/2/1/img.1.jpg
.../src_pics/1/2/1/img.2.jpg
...
.../src_pics/1/2/1/img.27.jpg
```

Since the image filenames themselves are not guaranteed to be unique, I'm looking for a way to inform sorl (at runtime) that I'd like to prefix thumbs for this model with the instance pk value.  Is this even possible without patching sorl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah hah.
Well it looks like the solution was staring me in the face the whole time.
http://thumbnail.sorl.net/docs/#this-just-doesn-t-cover-my-cravings

Looks like I'm going to subclass sorl.thumbnail.main.DjangoThumbnail and re-implement the _get_relative_thumbnail method to allow me to *inject* a template driven prefix for the thumbnail filename.

Comment: Perhaps I don't even need to do that... I need to do some testing as I'm not that familiar with the path of execution sorl goes though.  Looks like I may just be able to pass prefix in the template tag  as one of the keyword args.  That would be ideal.